# Some doubts about how exactly grid BootStrap component work?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am pretty new in BootStrap CSS framework and I have the following doubts about how BootStrap handle the grids to divide the space.

It seems to me that (correct me if I am saying wrong).

1) The **grid** component is used to divid the space into fluid columns (so the columns width is expresed in percentual)

2) It is based on 12 columns (what exactly means this assertion? that can I have maximum 12 columns? or what else?)

3) **12 columns** means **100%** of the available space, so it could be used the following "conversion table" to define the space of the columns:

```
.col-sm-1  { width: 8.333333333333332%;  }
.col-sm-2  { width: 16.666666666666664%; }
.col-sm-3  { width: 25%;                 }
.col-sm-4  { width: 33.33333333333333%;  }
.col-sm-5  { width: 41.66666666666667%;  }
.col-sm-6  { width: 50%;                 }
.col-sm-7  { width: 58.333333333333336%; }
.col-sm-8  { width: 66.66666666666666%;  }
.col-sm-9  { width: 75%;                 }
.col-sm-10 { width: 83.33333333333334%;  }
.col-sm-11 { width: 91.66666666666666%;  }
.col-sm-12 { width: 100%;                }
```

So my doubt is:

if I have the following grid:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-6">
  ...
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-3">
  ...
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-3">
  ...
 </div>
</div>
```

it means that I have a "table" composed by a single row that is divided into 3 columns and that:

FIRST COLUMN (on the left) fill the 50% of the space

SECOND COLUMN (in the center) fill the 25% of the space

THIRD COLUMN (on the right) fill the 25% of the space

Is it my reasoning correct? is it the way in wich BootStrap Grid component work?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: Did you *try* it?  What didn't work about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion you are completely right. So I can only give an answer to the following:

> 2) It is based on 12 columns (what exactly means this assertion? that can I have maximum 12 columns? or what else?)

I think 12 was choose as number because it is quite well divisible by other numbers (1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12). But it does not mean, that you are only able to have at most 12 columns since you can nest the elements:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- and so on (in sum 12 times) -->
</div>
```

This would result in 24 columns. And of course you are free to modify to get the number and width of columns like you wish.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-6">
  ...
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-3">
  ...
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-3">
  ...
 </div>
</div> 

FIRST COLUMN (on the left) fill the 50% of the space

SECOND COLUMN (in the center) fill the 25% of the space

THIRD COLUMN (on the right) fill the 25% of the space
```

Your assumption is correct only if **container width** is 768px or greater.

Once Width is less than 768px, each column becomes 100%.

Read the [Grid-Option](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options). You can test it at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bYb3J/).

[image]

If you want each column width vary by container width, you can stack those classes. For example,

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-3 col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See the demo at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gFuGj/)